# Best practice to peer-review a LaTeX document?

Tags: best-practices, collaboration

I'm currently writing a big document in LaTeX. The language is English and since I'm not a native English speaker, I've found a friend who will review and correct the document for me as soon as I have finished it.

Now I'm thinking about how this can be done. I don't want him to change the original version of my documents, since maybe I don't want to include all the modifications. So how can I best compare two different versions of LaTeX documents to see what he has changed?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [What is a good strategy for obtaining comments on a LaTeX document from non-LaTeX using collaborators?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/what-is-a-good-strategy-for-obtaining-comments-on-a-latex-document-from-non-latex)

Comment: Using a revision control system like subversion or git could be helpful, too. This way prior versions don't get lost and you don't need to email the document back and forth, including all the images and files that go with it. If you want to keep it low tech, consider using dropbox.com. `latexdiff` could still be used to highlight changes.

Comment: @Seamus: I don't think it is a duplicate, since if I understand Roflcoptr correctly, his/her friend knows LaTeX.

Comment: @Caramdir yes I knows LaTeX (probably more than me ;))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The preferred way is [`latexdiff`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/). You'll need to have Perl installed, as this is really a 
script.

The usage is quite simple (see below), but check the documentation for more options.

```
latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

On an unrelated note, I had a question some time ago about [comparing PDF documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/how-to-track-changes-between-pdfs), but hopefully you won't need that.

You might also find [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232/how-can-you-use-latex-to-write-a-document-with-other-people) helpful, which is partly related to what you're asking.

Comment: +1, I used `latexdiff` very successful in the review process of my last papers. I always sent my co-authors a full updated and a diff version of the PDF. They printed it out and gave me there nodes back.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and the problem is I always get the error 'The Perl interpreter could not be found' although I installed perl.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Check whether your Perl interpreter is in your path. You're probably using Windows (in Linux getting this error would be pretty hard if you use normal installation mechanisms), so check Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environmental Variables and see whether the path to your perl interpreter executable is included in the PATH variable.

Comment: Yes it is. I checked this already yesterday. Or btw... was is the executable? The bin folder?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: The executable is in the bin folder (perl.exe), so your path will contain something like "C:\Perl\bin", or wherever you installed it. Try running it from the command line directly (write "perl" and see what happens). BTW you might want to drop in chat to continue troubleshooting there.

Comment: Google `windows add to path` or some such in order to find help on how to update your `PATH` environmental variable.