# Comparing the output of two PDFs

Tags: pdf, comparison

Sometimes I want to compare the results of two different settings to see which gives better results (e.g. during the final fine tuning before handing in a document). Such settings can result in small changes in the location of words and other elements of the document.

### Motivation

Seeing the documents side-by-side on screen is not always enough, and the cost of printing is too great.

- Is there a method for overlaying two resulting PDFs (e.g. one PDF is transparent) so that the differences can be easily compared?
- What other methods can one use to compare two PDFs?

Comment: See also: [How to track changes between PDFs?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/how-to-track-changes-between-pdfs)

Comment: Another tool to consider is <a href="http://www.antennahouse.com/antenna-house-regression-testing-system/">AHRTS</a>. Its not free, but it does a good job.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can try [`pdfpagediff`](http://www.cvr.cc/?p=201) package:

```
\usepackage{pdfpagediff}
\layerPages[<optional page numbers>]{<file1>}{<file2>}
```

Answer (score 26):

Check:

[PDFPageDiff](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpagediff)

and

[DiffPDF (free version)](http://soft.rubypdf.com/software/diffpdf)

The first link is a to a Latex package *pdfpagediff*, which, according to the author will

> create a composite PDF by juxtaposing each page of
>   file1.pdf over the corresponding page of file2.pdf or
>   vice-versa. Since the PDFs are transparent, you can
>   notice the slightest change visually by simply flipping
>   through the pages

The other link is to a little windows program call *DiffPDF*, a PDF comparison tool that shows the differences in PDF files either textually or visually. You will also find it as a portable application at

[PortableApps DiffPDF 2.1.3](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/diffpdf_portable)

As Florian mentions in his comment, you can download a Mac version from [German CNET](http://de.download.cnet.com/DiffPDF/3000-18497_4-75745980.htm)

**UPDATE 28 Jan 2016**

Since I wrote this answer, the *DiffPDF* you will find on the qtrac.eu's homepage (link in Florian's comment) is commercial software, very expensive and with a very restrictive license. The links in my answer are still valid and link to what probably is an older, free version of the software, or maybe a totally different software. I am not sure.

Comment: I'm a very happy user of diffpdf. The acutal developer's page is [http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html) where you also can find links to a precompiled Mac version.

Comment: Could you please include some information on diffpdf in your post for completeness (and in case the links die).

Comment: @Florian The DiffPDF you link, has become an expensive, commercial software! The DiffPDF I link to, is free software. I suggest you either delete your comment.

Comment: That's unfortunately correct: Qtrac not only changed the licensing of the newer versions, they also removed the older ones -- which are still perfectly useable; the old page is archived here: http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf-foss.html I haven't tried the new commercial versions either and don't intend to with that price tag and license. Your diffpdf-link is indeed to the old version, unfortunately without a Mac-binary. But you can get the old Mac-binary from other places, e.g. cnet http://de.download.cnet.com/DiffPDF/3000-18497_4-75745980.htm

Comment: @Florian I am on Windows and use the portable version (2.1.3). Is it OK that I copy the link to the Mac-version into my answer?

Comment: @Sveinung Most certainly yes :) (It should also be possible to compile from source but a quick test ran into several problems. On the other hand it doesn't really matter, as long as nobody is developing it further anyway. So I will not investigate this any further for now.)

Comment: Both are great tools, at least for what I need. A pitty DiffPDF cannot capture certain changes (even in word/character mode), like URLs behind linked text.

Answer (score 18):

I use the image comparison tool from [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) which is available under Linux and Windows (and also Mac, IIRC). It generates a raster image where everything identical is semi-transparent, but the differences are highlighted in red. One drawback is that you have to raster the PDFs and this has to be done page-wise. For example, to compare the first page of two PDFs you can use:

```
compare -metric PSNR -density 300 first.pdf[0] second.pdf[0] diff0.png
```

Where 0 stands for the first page (computers start to count at 0). Replace it with 1 for the second and with 2 for the third page, etc. The density is used for the vector to raster image conversion needed. Use higher values for a higher resolution, which takes more space and conversion time, of course. The optional `-metric PSNR` option also prints the difference as signal-to-noise ratio.

I wrote myself the following shell script `comparepdfs` which takes the two PDFs as two arguments and produces `<number>diff.png` files for all pages which show the differences.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILEA=$1
FILEB=$2
OUTFILE=$3

if [[ -z "$OUTFILE" ]]; then
    OUTFILE="diff.png"
fi

DENSITY=72

PAGESA=$(pdfinfo "$FILEA" | grep ^Pages: | sed 's/Pages:\s*//')
PAGESB=$(pdfinfo "$FILEB" | grep ^Pages: | sed 's/Pages:\s*//')

if [[ $PAGESA > $PAGESB ]];
then
    PAGES=$(($PAGESA-1))
else
    PAGES=$(($PAGESB-1))
fi

for N in `seq 0 "$PAGES"`; do
    echo "Comparing page $N / $PAGES."
    compare -metric PSNR -density "$DENSITY" "$FILEA[$N]" "$FILEB[$N]" "${N}$OUTFILE";
done
```

Comment: The comparison fails. Error: `compare: image widths or heights differ `XY.pdf' @ error/compare.c/CompareImageCommand/962`. I'm on Linux.

Comment: @KeksDose: Looks like your two PDFs don't have the same size, but this is a requirement with this code.

Answer (score 16):

Imagemagick provides a [compare](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) utility to compare the differences between two image files. The [compare-pdfs.sh](http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/contexttest/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Futils%2Fcompare-pdfs.sh&revision=40&view=markup) script from the [ConTeXt test suite](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Test) splits the pdf into multiple pages and then uses imagemagick's `compare` to compare each page.

Answer (score 12):

You can open the two pdf files as a layers of a single image in [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), and make the top layer semitransparent.  You can also set the top layer to "subtract" or "difference" mode, so you will clearly see the differences between the two layers.

Answer (score 6):

I've had a similar problem to the one in this thread. However, all the solutions proposed here were not suitable for my situation, since I wanted to compare (mostly) text changes.

Moreover, the changes were not "minimal", and the new document was several pages longer than the old one. For instance, I have not been able to make *pdfpagediff* work. As for the *diffpdf* tool, It seems that it can only compare PDFs with the same length, which made it unsuitable for my needs. I also didn't like the output produced when using the *compare* alternative.

Hence, my suggestion, if you have the LaTex sources, is to use the command latexdiff. It is quite simple, you just have to generate the differences between the .tex and .bbl sources. I've used the following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "\nUsage: $0 <old file> <new file> [-d | --debug]"
    echo -e "\n\tFile names must be specified without extensions, e.g.:"
    echo -e "\n\t\t'paper' instead of 'paper.tex' or 'paper.bib'"
    echo -e "\n\t-d | --debug do not deletes the generated temporary files.\n"
    exit 0
fi

old=$1
new=$2

# Process old file sources
latex $old
bibtex $old
latex $old
latex $old

# Process new file sources
latex $new
bibtex $new
latex $new
latex $new

latexdiff "${old}.bbl" "${new}.bbl" > diff.bbl 
latexdiff "${old}.tex" "${new}.tex" > diff.tex

# Generate pdf
latex diff
latex diff
dvips -Ppdf -ta4 diff.dvi -o diff.ps 
ps2pdf diff.ps

# If debug, exit, otherwise, remove temporary files
if [[ $3 = "-d" || $3 = "--debug" ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

rm diff.tex diff.bbl diff.aux diff.dvi diff.log diff.out diff.ps diff.spl
```

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not the best tool for your particular use case, but the hint may be useful for other users who look for "Comparing the output of two PDFs" in a more general sense:

Adobe Acrobat Pro (unfortunately not the free Reader) provides a pretty good "Compare Documents..." feature, which produces a page-wise "diff PDF" out of two PDF documents. Acrobat does a great deal in not comparing pixels, but logical content (especially text), so that editorial changes are easy to detect.

I use this to check, for instance, if my students have incorporated the changes I asked them to do into the draft of their thesis.

Comment: While being accurate well presented, AA's comparison feature (at least vers. 9 on the Mac) is terribly slow, frequently crashes the application and has an absurd 250-pages limit. IMO nothing worth purchasing the software for.

Comment: @Florian: Thats true. It might be worthwhile to test the Windows version, though – given that on MacOS in general AA crashes a lot :-( In fact, I lost a lot of commenting and correction work by using AA on OSX; these days I use AA mostly from inside a Fusion VM, that is, under Windows. Ridiculously, this is not only more stable, but also **a lot** faster than using the native OSX version.

Comment: My experience is that this Acrobat Pro feature is very good when the changes between documents are minor and local. So, tweaks to a figure or a typo fix that doesn't cause a change of line breaking/pagination that propagates beyond the initial paragraph are fine. A document-wide font change or a floating figure that moves to a different page will cause far too many changes, make the compare process extremely slow and produce so many differences that the result is almost useless. Good for checking tweaks from a coauthor, bad for checking journal-supplied proofs against your manuscript.

Answer (score 1):

I used the online tool which does not require any additional installation: [this](https://gist.github.com/napsternxg/9e20d68dbd977573fb01c9e5a3f2bcdd)
They say they do not save your original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable using the terminal, you can use `diff-pdf` which has more functionality and is free:

`$ brew install diff-pdf`

then run

`$ diff-pdf --output-diff=diff.pdf first.pdf second.pdf`