# Superimpose pages

Tags: graphics

I was wondering how to superimpose the content of two different pages.

The aim is to see that the lines and page dimensions of odd page is correctly and strictly aligned with the even one. How can this be done?

Comment: Related [Comparing the output of two PDFs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36351/15717)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume you have a document containing your two-side document (I'll use `lipsum50.pdf`, since it contains 50 paragraphs of *Lorem Ipsum* style dummy text). Now create a stand-alone document with the following layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[page=1]{lipsum50}}
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[page=2]{lipsum50}}
}%
\mbox{}\pagestyle{empty}% Just set something on an empty page
\end{document}
```

[`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) provides the anchor `\AtPageLowerLeft` where you can place different `page`s from `lipsum50.pdf` and see how they overlay with one another.

Here is a close-up of the first two pages overlaid:

[image]