# Package or tool for visualizing differences

Tags: highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good way to show changes between two versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/what-is-a-good-way-to-show-changes-between-two-versions)

I done a bunch of updates in an article. I have a copy of an old revision of the paper. Now I would like to generate a PDF/DVI illustrating the updates I've done.

Is there any tool or package that would help me with this?

(The article is under SVN version control, if that helps.)

Comment: [DiffPDF](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html) can show you difference between two PDFs, but it won't generate new PDF showing them. Just a not really helpful side note, in case you don't know this tool.

Comment: As well as the question @Martin linked, other possibly related questions are http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4182/best-latex-aware-diff-and-merge-tools-for-subversion, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10134/texdiff-for-multi-file-documents-in-subversion, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/how-to-track-changes-between-pdfs, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/821/mark-changes-since-last-edition-with-bars-in-the-margin and probably others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a useful Perl script to display differences between two LaTeX files: it creates a new LaTeX file that, when compiled, highlights changes with different colors. It is called [`latexdiff`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/) and also works with version control files.